# What are your favorite books or textbooks dealing with operator algebras?

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, book-recommendation, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

The title has it all. I am looking for some books with lot of exercises, and not very hard to read.

Comment: Murphy's book is the standard choice for the theory. I don't like the exercises though, so I would also suggest Davidson's book Cstar algebras by example. It has lots of exercises, but it's more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I found Murphy's text to be highly accessible. It also contains a lot of nice exercise.

[https://www.amazon.com/Algebras-Operator-Theory-Gerard-Murphy/dp/0125113609](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0125113609)